# Access certain location in array of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I want to enter in 3 names into the array. Then I want to access the position of the second character in the second name.

First of all I get an out of bounds exception in line 13. Also, the second for loop I know is completely off so excuse that.

Why am I getting the exception and how would I access certain character positions in certain strings?

```
class Names
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int index;
        String names[];
        names = new String [3];

        for(index = 1; index <= names.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter name " + index);
                names[index] = EasyIn.getString();
            }
        for(index = 0; index < names.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println(names[1][2]);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229986/get-string-character-by-index-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

You can make the `array` of `String` objects in one go like `String[] names = new String[3]`.

In your first loop you start like this:

```
for(index = 1; index <= names.length; index++)
```

That is wrong, you start with your index at `0` unless you want to skip the first element. Then you define `index <= names.length;`, which is also wrong. The length returns the actual length, but we now know an `array` starts at 0. You should define it like this:

```
for(index = 0; index < names.length; index++)
```

As others have said before, if you want to get a certain char from the string you use `myString.charAt(  )', so in your case you should write something like this:

```
System.out.println(names[<an index>].charAt(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create static array and than read the value from it

```
String[] array = {"Peter", "John", "Andre"}; //now you have three items in array
char secondChar = array[1].charAt(1); //first get second element, than get second char from it
```

So now `secondChar` is `o` - also remember that arrays starts from `0` so that's why index `1` means second item in the array - same applies for `charAt`, String is just basically array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
        int index;
        String names[];
        names = new String [3];

        for(index = 0; index < names.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name " + index);
            names[index] = EasyIn.getString();
        }
        for(index = 0; index < names.length; index++)
        {
            if (names[index] != null && names[index].length() > 2)
                System.out.println(names[index].charAt(2));
        }
```

Comment: OK, just one more thing. This only allows me to enter 2 names. Once I enter 2 names it skips to the second for loop immediately without allowing me to enter the third name.

Comment: I don't know what your "EasyIn.getStrig()" function is doing, but it is definitely called three times. You should see the output.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> in ur first loop:

```
for(index = 0; index < names.length; index++)
```

> remove ur second loop as don't wana show each element, u can do it directly like this:

```
System.out.println(names[1].charAt(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a certain character in a string, use `mystring.charAt(index)`