# How do I fix Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of vowels in the string. The problem is that it compiles correctly, but when I run it the command window says "Exception in thread 'main' *java.lang.NullPointerException* at *CountVowels.main(**CountVowels.java:25**)*.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CountVowels
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String thingy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a sentence, and I  will count the vowels.");
        int count = 0;

        char[] chars = new char[thingy.length()];
        String[] letters = new String[thingy.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < thingy.length(); ++i)
        {
            chars[i] = thingy.charAt(i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i)
        {
            letters[i].valueOf(chars[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
        {
            if(letters[i].equals("a") || letters[i].equals("e") || letters[i].equals("i") || letters[i].equals("o") || letters[i].equals("u"))
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in the string + " + thingy);
    }
}
```

What causes this, how can I fix it, and how can I prevent it from happening again in the future?

line 25 is my if statement:

```
if(letters[i].equals("a") || letters[i].equals("e") || letters[i].equals("i") || letters[i].equals("o") || letters[i].equals("u"))
                {
                    ++count;
                }
```

Comment: And which is line 25 ?

Comment: This line isn't doing what you think it is: `letters[i].valueOf(chars[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
letters[i].valueOf(chars[i]);
```

does nothing. If you change it to

```
letters[i] = String.valueOf(chars[i]);
```

you will set all the elements in `letters` to the corresponding characters. That should fix your `NullPointerException`.

You can also save a lot of code by using a bit of regex trickery:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CountVowels
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a sentence, and I will count the vowels.");
        String[] letters = input.split("(?<=.)(?=.)");

        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            if(letters[i].matches("[aeiou]"))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in the string + " + input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
letters[i] = "" + chars[i];
```

Also, you don't need to go through all the hassle of creating new arrays going from String to chars to String. Read this question for more information about accessing each character from a String (so you can just check the letters in the `thingy` object without creating more arrays)

[Get string character by index - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229986/get-string-character-by-index-java)

Comment: Thanks for the info, this will definitely save me some time

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
      import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
      class CountVowels
     {
       public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      String thingy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a sentence, and I  will count the vowels.");
     int count = 0;
     char[] c=thingy.toCharArray();
     for(int i = 0; i < c.length; ++i)
     {
        if(c[i]=='a' || c[i]=='e' || c[i]=='i' || c[i]=='o' || c[i]=='u')
        {
            ++count;
         }
      }
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in the string + " + thingy);
   }
 }
```

output :
        [image]

Answer (score 0):

Array `letters` is empty. It contains `null` values.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i)
        {
            letters[i].valueOf(chars[i]);
        }

Didn't this assign the values?

Comment: @Beninemm No, it didn't.

Comment: No. You can check it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mis in your code. When you manipulate with String, the return string should be taken for furthur processing.. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

letters[i] = String.valueOf(chars[i]);