# How to get name between some string?

Tags: java, android, string, indexing

i want to get a string between some given string

like this..

```
String wholetext = "SomePlace Pin- 110065 Name and address Alias 1 ID of customer-123 SomePlace "
String namerequired =  "";
String textafter = "110065 Name and address";
String textbefore = "ID of customer";

//Constant part-110065 Name and address and ID of customer
```

googled and get some thing like this [doindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229986/get-string-character-by-index-java)
and this [doindexing1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string)

i am trying to get **Alias 1** and not getting idea :( ?
Help please

Comment: what exactly have u tried? and what u got?

Comment: Are you trying to get the string between `**`?

Comment: give example what you want its seems very essay use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: just want to print alias 1... @akoskm

Comment: It is very much going to depend on what you want from your String. I mean which part of the String do you want? Is there a constant part of the String after which you want to get some user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
    String wholetext = "Place Then Pin- **110065 Name and address** Alias 1 ID of customer-123 Some Place ";
    String textafter = "110065 Name and address";
    String textbefore = "ID of customer";

    int index1 = wholetext.indexOf(textbefore);
    int index2 = wholetext.indexOf(textafter) + textafter.length();

    String namerequired = wholetext.substring(index2, index1);
    System.out.println(namerequired);
```

Output:

```
    Alias 1
```

But using a regex or String matcher would probably be better.

Comment: If you want it without space, use wholetext.substring(intex2 +1, index1 - 1)

Comment: Thnx for answer bro :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regexes(Regular Expressions).
there are a lot of regex learning sites over internet.
i hope this helps.

Comment: can u give me example of regex for above question? @mrkalan

Answer (score 1):

If waht you want is after the last occurence of **, you can try

```
String substring = wholetext.substring(wholetext.lastIndexOf("**"));
System.out.println(substring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Java's Pattern matching to solve your problem. This will help you solve your current problem and any future `Regex` problems

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html