# Android How to get first character of string?

Tags: java, string

How to get first character of string?

```
string test = "StackOverflow";
```

first character = "S"

Comment: take a look at this tutorial [charAt()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get string character by index - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229986/get-string-character-by-index-java)

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. I voted to close due to it being a duplicate.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
String test = "StackOverflow"; 
char first = test.charAt(0);
```

Comment: or `substring(0,1)` if you want it as a String instead of a character

Comment: this will throw an error if you do `textView.setText(test.charAt(0))` as it's a char not string.

Comment: This is what @Thilo is trying to say:   ` **String test = "StackOverflow"; 
String first = test.substring(0,1);</code>**`

Answer (score 73):

Another way is

```
String test = "StackOverflow";
String s=test.substring(0,1);
```

In this you got result in `String`

Answer (score 5):

You can refer this [link](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html), point 4.

```
public class StrDemo
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String abc = "abc";

    System.out.println ("Char at offset 0 : " + abc.charAt(0) );
    System.out.println ("Char at offset 1 : " + abc.charAt(1) );
    System.out.println ("Char at offset 2 : " + abc.charAt(2) );

  //Also substring method
   System.out.println(abc.substring(1, 2));
   //it will print
```

> bc

```
// as starting index to end index here in this case abc is the string 
   //at 0 index-a, 1-index-b, 2- index-c

// This line should throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    System.out.println ("Char at offset 3 : " + abc.charAt(3) );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use charAt():

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "Stackoverflow";
      char result = s.charAt(0);
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm)