# How to set specific characters of a string to a text view instead of whole string?

Tags: android, string, textview

I've a string with complete language name and I wanted to set first two characters of that language name to my text view. Like I've a language name AFRIKAANS and I only wanted to set AF on my text view. How can I do this

Comment: This is clearly answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010602/android-how-to-get-first-character-of-string/26010631

Comment: @Rajasekhar or even better, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217815/extract-first-two-characters-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String string = "AFRIKAANS";
yourTextView.setText(string.substring(0, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substring` method like this

```
"AFRIKAANS".substring(0,2)
```