# Why isn' this counting vowels?

Tags: java, count

I need to count the vowels but this is always returning 0?

```
public static int numVowel(String s) {
  int count = 0,x;
  for(x = 0; x<s.length();x++)
    if (x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u' || x=='A' || x=='E' || x=='I' || x=='O' || x=='U')
    count++;
  return count;
}
```

Comment: `x` is only an index into string `s`. You must retrieve the character at position `x` and compare it with the vowels.

Comment: What do you think that `x` is? What is its type? When is it set and to what value is it set?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your *counter/index* against char literals.

Instead, you should retrieve the character at the indexed position against these literals! See [Get string character by index - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229986/get-string-character-by-index-java) here for how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `s.charAt(x) == 'a'` instead of `x == 'a'`. 
You should check the character at the given index.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check the value of `x`; you want to check the value of the character at position `x`. You can do this with `s.charAt(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `x` is your index (not the characters from `s`). Also, always use braces (even when they're optional). To fix it with your current approach, do something like

```
public static int numVowel(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char x = s.charAt(i);
        if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' || x == 'A' || x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O'
                || x == 'U') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But I would prefer something like

```
public static int numVowel(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if ("aeiou".indexOf(ch) > -1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Or use a regular expression to remove everything that isn't a vowel from the input `String` and then return the length of that. Like,

```
public static int numVowel(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "").length();
}
```

If you need to invoke this many many times then the cost of calling `String.toLowerCase()` is not insignificant; and you might compile that regex into a `Pattern`.

```
private static Pattern _PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^aeiouAEIOU]");
public static int numVowel(String s) {
    return _PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll("").length();
}
```